# Inserting content into MYSQL table columns with certain search criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am pretty new to MYSQL tables, pretty limited experience.

I have a wordpress table (using PHPmyadmin) and basically, I want to add template content into all posts that have the below search criteria.

I honestly have no idea, I just need the bit where I can insert text (template text) all at once, not individually to the posts with the below criteria.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_title` LIKE 'best hotel deals in%'
AND `post_status` LIKE 'draft'
```

Hope this makes sense!

OK, the post_content fields are **blank** at the moment and I want to fill it with basic text for example:

"the fox jumps over the fence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn SQL, simple solution for you is:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` set `colname`=CONCAT(`colname`, 'additional content')
WHERE `post_title` LIKE 'best hotel deals in%'
AND `post_status` LIKE 'draft'
```

if you want to update all posts - just remove `where...` condition

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add text to the beginning or end of the post content, you can do something like this:

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = concat(post_content, 'extra text you want to add')
where
    post_title like 'best hotel deals in%' and
    post_status = 'draft'
```

Be careful, though, particularly if you're not an experienced MySQL or WordPress user.  Messing around directly in the database tables can really screw up your WordPress installation if you're not careful.